# variable set in brace group doesn't keep value outside

Tags: shell

When a variable is set inside braced statements, the value is also known outside.
`{ i=4; } ; echo "$i"` will output `4`.

I wanted to be clever and use that to transmit metadata alongside some data (that can contain null-bytes - so no variables).
So my program pipes some data into a braced group of statements where it is read - as expected - but the variables aren't changed outside and I can't find the part of the spec that says they shouldn't.

My first guess was that a sneaky subshell was created cause of the pipe but I've checked the PID in- and outside.
Reading into a temp variable and then assigning to the outside var also doesn't work.

Here's some code to reproduce (the error ;-):

```bash
finished=0
pos=0

echo "pid outside: $$"

(
  # placeholder code
  echo 1
  echo 1
  echo "data"
) | {
  echo "pid inside: $$"
  read pos
  read finished
  echo "pos: $pos"
  echo "finished: $finished"
  # instead of the echos, cat would output the data here
}

echo "pos outside: $pos"
echo "finished outside: $finished"
```

Output:

```
pid outside: 139840
pid inside: 139840
pos: 1
finished: 1
pos outside: 0
finished outside: 0
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The command group is part of a pipeline, so it's executed in a subshell.

Comment: More details: [why can't I pipe data to read?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: do you want to put that into an answer?

Comment: i can as well, but you might want the rep.
`< <(generator)` or `mkfifo $tmp; exec 4<>$tmp ; rm $tmp ; generator >&4 & read <&4 ; cat <&4` - dunno, something like that